# Python how can I print which sentence a word is in?

Tags: python, printing, frequency

Making a concordance program. I want it to tell me what sentence a word is in, so if I have:

"Hello world. My name is Nathan and I need help on Python. I am very confused and any help is appreciated."

I want it to print which sentence each word comes from. I already have completed that it counts the total number of times each word appears and next to it I need the sentence number(s) it comes from, so it displays as:

```
a. word {word appearance count:sentence number}
```

with 'a.' working as the list order (like a numbered list but with letters). An example from the first sentence would be

```
a. help {2:2,3}
```

Here's the code I currently have:

```
word_counter = {}
sent_num = {}
linenum = 0
wordnum = 0
counter = 0

#not working
for word in f.lower().split('.'):
    if not word in sent_num:
        sent_num[word] = []
    sent_num[word].append(f.find(wordnum))


#working correctly
for word in f.lower().split():
if not word in word_counter:
        word_counter[word] = []
        #if the word isn't listed yet, adds it
    word_counter[word].append(linenum)

for key in sorted(word_counter):
    counter += 1
    print (counter, key, len(word_counter[key]), len(sent_num[key]))
```

Comment: `linenum` is always `0`

Comment: This is a broad question as there is lots wrong with your code. It's difficult to answer without completely rewriting. I don't think the answer will be useful for future generations. Split the question into smaller more specific chunks, read about how to create a [mcve], and maybe ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple to iterate over each sentence then each word in that sentence and create a dictionary that maps `{word: [sentence, ...]}`:

```
In [1]:
d = {}
for i, sent in enumerate(f.lower().split('. ')):
    for w in sent.strip().split():
        d.setdefault(w, []).append(i)
d

Out[1]:
{'am': [2],
 'and': [1, 2],
 'any': [2],
 'appreciated.': [2],
 'confused': [2],
 'hello': [0],
 'help': [1, 2],
 ...}
```

Given the list is all the occurrences of the word then you can just get the count by call `len()`, e.g.:

```
In [2]:
len(d['help'])

Out[2]:
2
```

Comment: I have no issues with people down-voting but please leave a message if you do. It's hard to improve without feedback.

Comment: This mostly worked! Thank you so much! Only problem I am having now is that I cannot remove the period after 'testing.' which is breaking my code. Apparently I cannot strip('.') from a dictionary? It is counting 'testing' and 'testing.' as two different words.

Comment: You could try `split('.')` (no space after period), you may need to `strip()` any superfluous spaces.

Comment: One issue of splitting with `split('.')` are sentences like 'Mr. Miller is nice. ...'. The cleaner, but more sophisticated approach would be a sentence boundary detection system, e.g. by parsing the text with spaCy or NLTK.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm guessing this is likely an elementary exercise given the OPs experience.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you look at full sentences, you are only splitting on `'.'`. You need to split each sentence into words, after that:

```
for sentence in f.split('.'):
    for word in sentence.lower().split():
        if not word in sent_num:
            sent_num[word] = []
        sent_num[word].append(f.find(wordnum))
```

or something along those ways, depending on what you want to look at and count.

Comment: They only want to know if it's in the sentence.